Will a 6” vent pipe be effective for my kitchen exhaust?
I am looking to install a vented exhaust in my condo kitchen. Per the contractor who is very experienced with homes that are similar to mine, we would need about 50ft of vent pipe to get from the kitchen to the exterior.
The vent pipe would be fitted between the crawl space of my first and second floor. For additional context the joists for 2nd floor are trusses- w/ diagonal braces every 16", including  wiring, plumbing, hvac ducts etc.
I am looking to get the 30” Zephyr Typhoon which has 850 CFM (see details here: http://docs.zephyronline.com/docs/manuals/typhoonc_manual.pdf).
Per the contractor we will have to use a 6” vent pipe given the area it will sit in. Will a 6” vent pipe damper the effectiveness of the fan? Additionally are there any safety issues with using a 6” vent pipe?

Duct size needed varies with the length of the run—the longer it is, the more head loss there is, even with a large diameter.  The instructions say the Typhoon is pre-configured for 7" ducting.  If you look on p11 of the instructions, there's a worksheet that tells you how much headloss you need to account for.  So if you have 6" duct, you need a 7">6" adapter at the unit, that is worth 25ft of duct.  You'll have an outlet at the outside of the house, so that's another 30ft of duct.  Lengths of duct and elbows add more headloss.  So total up the headloss for whatever fittings and length of duct you'll have, and if it's less than or equal to 150ft, you're OK.
